# How to import ORMLite into my Android project?

Tags: android, ormlite

The guide written here only says which files I need for installing ORMLite:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/getting-started

But I don't see an explanation of how exactly I have to import these files into my project and where, and how to set the "classpath"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

1. Download the jars
2. Put it in your libs folder in project
3. add jar to class path.
4. Right Click on your project -> Build path -> Confiugre build path
5. Select libraries -> add Jar, then choose jar from your libs.

Comment: How do I set the class path? Edit: I think I found it. Right click on jar -> Build Path -> Add to build path.

Answer (score 2):

With the newest versions of ADT in Eclipse, this should be done automatically, you just need to drop the .jar into the libs folder, and it will be automatically added to the build path.